# How can I set a Date in Delphi with JNI

Tags: java, delphi, java-native-interface

I am creating a `class` in Delphi that will call methods in a Java class;

I had no problems with primitives/wrappers or String types, but I'm having problems with `Date`.

In java I have a `setDateStart(java.util.Date dateStart)` method, how can I call it in Delphi?

```
procedure TMyJavaObject.SetDateStart(const DateStart: TDateTime);
var
    method : JMethodID;
begin
    method := getMethod(self.clazz, 'setDateStart', '(Ljava/util/Date;)V');
    JNIEnv.CallVoidMethod(self.javaObject, method, [DateStart]);
end;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Ljava/uitl/Date` is misspelled. Should be `Ljava/util/Date` instead.

Also, a Delphi `TDateTime`, which is implemented as a `Double`, is not compatible with a Java `java.util.Date`, which is an object instance.  You need to create a real `Date` object instance and assign the `TDateTime` value to it as needed.

Try something more like this instead (I don't use JNI in Delphi, so this might need some tweaking, but you get the idea):

```
uses
    ..., DateUtils;

procedure TMyJavaObject.SetDateStart(const DateStart: TDateTime);
var
  DateValue: Int64; // a Java 'long' is a 64-bit type
  DateClass: JClass;
  DateObj: JObject;
  method : JMethodID;
begin
  // DateTimeToUnix() returns a value in seconds,
  // but the java.util.Date(long) constructor expects
  // a value in milliseconds instead...
  DateValue := DateTimeToUnix(DateStart) * 1000;

  // create a java.util.Date object instance, passing the
  // converted TDateTime value as a 'long' to its constructor...
  DateClass := JNIEnv.FindClass('java/util/Date');
  method := JNIEnv.GetMethodID(DateClass, '<init>', '(J)V');
  DateObj := JNIEnv.NewObject(DateClass, method, [DateValue]);

  // pass the java.util.Date object to the desired object method...
  method := getMethod(self.clazz, 'setDateStart', '(Ljava/util/Date;)V');
  JNIEnv.CallVoidMethod(self.javaObject, method, [DateObj]);
end;
```